# Keep a dropdown list opened after rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have three components, one based on class (AdmControls) and two functional (listarProdutos and listarProdutosItens). They are responsible for rendering a list fetched from Firebase.

Each one of the items may be deleted after a click, the function responsible for it is `excluirItemHandler` and is in `listarProdutosItens`.

Besides that the list is a dropdown list with two levels, I have a `h1` tag in `listarProdutos` and when I click on it the first level is shown, just the titles of each sublist, the `h2` tag in `excluirItemHandler`, then I am able to open the respective second level of each sublist by clicking on each title. In order to do that I am doing the classic way, using a state set to 'false' and changing it by a click, as I have two levels I need two states, `open` in `listarProdutos` and `openProd` in `excluirItemHandler`.

So far so good, but after removing the item from the DB the function `fetchListaProdutosHandler` in `AdmControls` is called by props and the data is fetched again, however after it happens the state `openProd` in `listarProdutosItens` is set to `false` and the list is closed, but it happens only with the respective list that had an item removed, if I have two sublists opened and remove an item from the first one, only the first one will be closed, the second one will be kept opened.

I believe this is happening because the component is being rerendering and the `state` is getting back to its original state. So, what I want is to keep the list opened after having an item removed and I imagine that if I be able to keep the `state` as `true` my problem will be solved, but I am trying to do that for some time and I got nothing.

Any ideas?

[image]

*AdmControls container:

```
class AdmControls extends Component {

state = {
    referenciaInput: 0,
    valor: '',
    nome: '',
    altura: '',
    furo: '',

    tipos:[]
}

fetchListaProdutosHandler() {
    axios.get('/adm.json')
        .then(res => {

            let inserirKeyCat = Object.entries(res.data).map(item => Object.entries(item[1]))
            inserirKeyCat.map(item => item.map(it => it[1]))
            inserirKeyCat.map(item => item.map(it => it[1]['key'] = it[0]))
            inserirKeyCat.map((item, i) => item.map(it => it[1]['categoria'] = Object.keys(res.data)[i]))

            let pedra = Object.keys(res.data.tipoPedra).map(key => res.data.tipoPedra[key]).sort((a,b) => a.nome.localeCompare(b.nome))
            let rod = Object.keys(res.data.tipoRodopia).map(key => res.data.tipoRodopia[key]).sort((a,b) => a.nome.localeCompare(b.nome))
            let acbPia = Object.keys(res.data.tipoAcabamento).map(key => res.data.tipoAcabamento[key]).sort((a,b) => a.nome.localeCompare(b.nome))
            let acbBanc = Object.keys(res.data.tipoAcabamentoSeco).map(key => res.data.tipoAcabamentoSeco[key]).sort((a,b) => a.nome.localeCompare(b.nome))
            let cuba = Object.keys(res.data.tipoCuba).map(key => res.data.tipoCuba[key]).sort((a,b) => a.nome.localeCompare(b.nome))
            let outros = Object.keys(res.data.outrosProdutos).map(key => res.data.outrosProdutos[key]).sort((a,b) => a.nome.localeCompare(b.nome))

            pedra.unshift({titulo: 'Tipo de Pedra'})
            rod.unshift({titulo: 'Tipo de Rodopia'})
            acbPia.unshift({titulo: 'Tipo de Acabamento Pia'})
            acbBanc.unshift({titulo: 'Tipo de Acabamento Seco'})
            cuba.unshift({titulo: 'Tipo de Cuba'})
            outros.unshift({titulo: 'Outros Produtos'})

            let tipos = [
                pedra,
                rod,
                acbPia,
                acbBanc,
                cuba,
                outros,
            ]

            this.setState({tipos})
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchListaProdutosHandler();
}   


render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <ListarProdutos produtosLista={this.state.tipos} fetchLista={() => this.fetchListaProdutosHandler()} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

*listarProdutos component:

```
const listarProdutos = props => {

const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

return (
    <div>
        <h1 style={{color: 'red'}} onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} >LISTA</h1>
        { open ?
            props.produtosLista.map((item, i) => <ListarProdutosItens listaItens={item} key={item+i} fetchLista={props.fetchLista} />)
        : null}

    </div>
  )
}
```

*listarProdutosItens:

```
const listarProdutosItens = props => {

const [openProd, setOpenProd] = React.useState(false);
console.log(openProd)

let itemTitulo = props.listaItens[0].titulo;

const excluirItemHandler = i => {

    let key = props.listaItens[i].key;
    let categoria = props.listaItens[i].categoria;

    axios.delete(`/adm/${categoria}/${key}.json`)
        .then(res => props.fetchLista())
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}


return (
    <div>
        <h2 onClick={() => setOpenProd(!openProd)} >{itemTitulo}</h2>

        {openProd ?
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Valor</th>
                        {
                            itemTitulo === 'Tipo de Acabamento Pia' || 
                            itemTitulo === 'Tipo de Rodopia' || 
                            itemTitulo === 'Tipo de Acabamento Seco' ? 
                            <th>Altura</th> 
                            : null
                        }
                        {itemTitulo === 'Tipo de Cuba' ? <th>Furo</th> : null}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {props.listaItens.map((it, i) => {

                    return (
                        i !== 0 ?
                        <thead key={it+i}>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{it.nome}</td>
                                <td>{it.valor}</td>
                                {
                                    itemTitulo === 'Tipo de Acabamento Pia' || 
                                    itemTitulo === 'Tipo de Rodopia' || 
                                    itemTitulo === 'Tipo de Acabamento Seco' ? 
                                        <td>{it.altura}</td> 
                                    : null
                                }
                                {itemTitulo === 'Tipo de Cuba' ? <td>{it.furo}</td> : null}
                                <td><button onClick={() => excluirItemHandler(i)} >Excluir</button></td>
                            </tr>

                        </thead>
                        : null
                    )
                })}
            </table>
        : null}
    </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code. It's kind of hard to follow. Have you tried isolating the issue? Maybe make an example replicating just the issue with the open/close component (no firebase) on https://codesandbox.io ?

Comment: @thor83. I would love to do that, but that's the point, I am not sure where the issue is. But in short, what I want is to keep a state unchanged after the component rerender, at least that is what I believe that is more likely to be the problem. But as I said, I am not sure.

Comment: I'm suggesting try to isolate the issue. Here is one approach. Move the open/close state for each list into the parent `<ListarProdutos />` instead of in `<ListarProdutosItens>` where you have it now. This would let you pass it as a prop to each `<ListarProdutosItens open={openListars[i]} />`. See if that allows the state to stay set as `open`.

Comment: Also, for debugging purpose, you can try adjusting the key you are passing to each `<ListarProdutosItens key={} />`. If the key changes the component will remount and your internal component state for `openProd` will be reset. It seems you are passing `item` which is an object or array? And also passing `i` which i'm guessing is an integer from the index of the loop. Maybe try something like `key={\`${item.id}-${i}\`}`

Comment: @thor83. Sorry about the delay. You were right, the problema was the `key` in `<ListarProdutos />`. I was passing an array as the `key` and had not even realized that, newbie mystakes lol. Thank you very much. If you want to edit your comment as an answer I'll be glad to accept it.